# Use of "and lo" in a sentence

Tags: grammar

What, if any, is the right way to use "and lo" in a sentence?

My basic structure is "[discussion about thing], and lo, [example of thing]", kind of like: There's a cliche about circus clowns being creepy and dangerous, and lo, last night I saw a clown violating a teddy bear.

Is this proper? Should there be a colon or semicolon after "lo"?

Comment: It should be noted that "and lo" is fairly archaic - the sort of phrasing you expect in traditional fairy tales, not in modern spoken English.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The words 'and lo' are usually followed by an exclamation mark (And lo! the majestic Himalayas, lay untrammeled before their very eyes!) , to emphasize the dramatic nature of the event that has come to pass. 'Lo and behold' is a related variant, also usually followed by an exclamation mark.

Answer (score 3):

**Lo** means **look** or **behold** [here/there]. It's not ordinarily used the way OP's example has it, where the amazing sight being referenced *isn't actually present at the time of speaking*.

In grammatical terms it's an interjection, so any alternative would also need to function in that way. For OP's example, I'd suggest **And would you believe it!** (an interjection, *not* a question).

Per @Karl's comment to the question, whilst not exactly "obsolete", it's at the very least least a "dated" usage in most conversational contexts today.